# What libraries are available for working with Apache Avro IDL?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I noticed there is no library listed in `melpa` for highlighting and working with [Apache Avro IDL](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/idl.html) schemata. Is there any, or else how people who work with Avro have set up their configuration to ease their work?

Comment: "how people who work with avro have set up their configuration to ease their work" is too broad. This site is more about specific how-to questions. Maybe you want to ask simply how to get syntax highlighting for avro files?

Comment: @Drew That is correct. However I’m definitely open to more encompassing answers.

Comment: It would help if you provided a description (and maybe some links) to what `avro` is. I googled it and the first hit says: " It uses JSON for defining data types and protocols...", so does a JSON library satisfy your requirements?  If so, there should be plenty to choose from.

Comment: @NickD As I became more knowledgeable on the subject I was able to formulate a more precise question. I changed the wording and included a link to the specification.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything, so I made it myself.

```lisp
;;; avro-mode.el -- major mode for editing Avro IDL files. -*- coding: utf-8; lexical-binding: t; -*-

;;; Copyright © by Daniel Vianna
;;; Version: 0.0.1
;;; Created: 19 Aug 2021

;;; Keywords: languages

;;; This file is not part of GNU Emacs.

;;; License:

;;; You can redistribute this program and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2.

;;; Package --- summary
;;; Commentary:
;;;
;;; Avro interface description language mode (.avdl)
;;; Code:

(require 'generic-x)

(define-generic-mode
    'avro-mode
  '("//") ;; comments
  '("protocol" "namespace") ;; reserved words
  '(("\\<[[:alnum:]]+\\>" (0 font-lock-builtin-face) ("\\<[[:alnum:]]+\\>;?\\( {\\)?" nil nil (0 nil))) ;; type
    ("\\<\\(?:namespace\\|protocol\\)\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face)
    
    ("{\\|}\\|;\\|<\\|>" . font-lock-constant-face)) ;; separators
  '("\\.avdl$") ;; file extension
  nil
  "Major mode for editing Avro IDL files."
  )

(provide 'avro-mode)

;;; avro-mode.el ends here
```